# Trie implementation in Python

Tags: python, trie

I tried to make this implementation clear. So I created `hasChild` function of `Node`. But why am I getting this this error?

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hasChild'

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,word):
        self.value = str(word)
        self.children = {}   
        self.isEndOfWord = False

    def hasChild(self,ch):
        return ch in self.children.keys()

    def addChild(self,ch):
        nodenew = Node(str(ch))
        self.children[ch] = nodenew

    def getChild(self,ch):
        return self.children.get(ch)

class Trie():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Node('')

    def insert(self,children):
        current = self.root
        for ch in children:
            if (current.hasChild(ch) is False):
                current.addChild(ch)
            current = self.root.getChild(ch)
        current.isEndOfWord = True
```

Comment: Can you please share the test code that produces the error?

Comment: the last few layers of the stack trace would be really userful here. Could you include those as well?

Comment: I don't imagine this is the cause of your issue, but `current.hasChild(ch) is False` should be written `not current.hasChild(ch)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed **current.hasChild(ch) is False** into **not current.hasChild(ch)** and **current = self.root.getChild(ch)** into **current = current.getChild(ch)** of the insert function. It works. Thanks a lot!

```
class Node():
def __init__(self,word):
    self.value = str(word)
    self.children = {}   
    self.isEndOfWord = False

def hasChild(self,ch):
    return ch in self.children.keys()

def addChild(self,ch):
    nodenew = Node(ch)
    self.children[ch] = nodenew

def getChild(self,ch):
    return self.children.get(ch)

class Trie():
def __init__(self):
    self.root = Node('')

def insert(self,children):
    current = self.root
    for ch in children:
        if (not current.hasChild(ch)):
            current.addChild(ch)
        current = current.getChild(ch)
    current.isEndOfWord = True

trie = Trie()
trie.insert('cat')
trie.insert('can')
```